# How to calculate a candlestick pattern

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm stuck creating an indicator that looks for a specific candlestick pattern.

The indicator should look for candlesticks where either the top or bottom wick is bigger than the candlestick body itself.

```
bodygreen = close[1] > open[1]
bodyRed = close[1] < open[1]

GwickTop = high[1] - close[1]
RwickTop = high[1] - open[1]

GwickBottom = open[1] - low[1]
RwickBottom = close[1] - low[1]

Gbody = close[1] - open[1]
Rbody = open[1] - close[1]

bullRev = (GwickBottom > (Gbody * 0.75)) or (RwickBottom > (Rbody * 0.75)) ? true : na
bearRev = (GwickTop > (Gbody * 0.75)) or (RwickTop > (Rbody * 0.75)) ? true : na

plotchar(bullRev, "Possible Bullish Reversal", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(bearRev, "Possible Bearish Reversal", shape.triangledown, location.abovebar, color.red, size = size.tiny)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this, removed the unnecessary steps and used `math.min()` / `math.max()` to determine the maximum and minimum of the body. Then script compares the size of the body, multiplied by the input, with the wicks at the top and bottom of the candle.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Candlestick Patterns", overlay = true)

float factor    = input.float(0.75, "Body Factor")

float bodyLow    = math.min(open, close)
float bodyHigh   = math.max(open, close)
float body       = bodyHigh - bodyLow
float topWick    = high - bodyHigh
float bottomWick = bodyLow - low

bool  bullRev    = bottomWick > body * factor ? true : na
bool  bearRev    = topWick > body * factor ? true : na

plotchar(bullRev, "Possible Bullish Reversal", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, color.lime, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(bearRev, "Possible Bearish Reversal", shape.triangledown, location.abovebar, color.red, size = size.tiny)
```